# Universal xpath query

Tags: html, xpath

Here's the situation. I have to retrieve some info from HTML pages from different domains. On one domain the info I need looks like this:

```
<div class='class1'>
     <span class='class2'> TEXT I NEED </span>
</div>
```

On the other there is no that span tag:

```
<div class='class1'> TEXT I NEED </div>
```

Is there an universal xpath query for retrieving the text for both cases instead of using **if** statements ?

Here's what I got so far:

```
if domain == 'com':
    rating = x.xpath('//span[@class="class2"]/text()')
if domain == 'de':
    rating = x.xpath('//div[@class="class1"]/text()')
```

Comment: ... in other words `string(//div[@class="class1"])` or `normalize-space(//div[@class="class1"])`

Answer (score 2):

Given just the HTML provided:

```
//*[contains(@class,'class1')]/descendant::text()
```

[image]